# How to get the value from a label

Tags: php, html, forms, post, if-statement

Okay so the problem is that I have a label which is in a form and I'm trying to access this label when I press a button, my form looks like:

```
<form method = 'POST'>
<img src = 'ItemIcons/<?php echo $ItemPicture;?>.png' alt = '<?php echo $row["ItemDesc"];?>'/>
<label name = 'lblItemName'><?php echo $ItemName; ?></label> 
<br>
<label> <?php echo "Gold:" . $row["ItemPrice"]; ?> </label> 


<input type = 'submit' value = 'Buy <?php echo $ItemName; ?>' name = 'ItemPurchase'/>
</form>
```

and my code for calling the button looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST['ItemPurchase'])) {
    $ItemName = $_POST["lblItemName"];
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('<?php echo $ItemName;?>');
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Currently it alerts an empty value, it works when I place it as a textbox and not a label, but it needs to be a label sadly, any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Either use javascript to get label value and submit, or place a hidden input (input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $row["ItemPrice"]; ?>") and use this as formdata when submitting the form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Labels aren't submitted with forms, so it isn't going to work the way you have it. Why not create a hidden input field beneath it that echoes the same value? Then your $_POST[''] will work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="lblItemName" value="<?php echo $ItemName; ?>">
```

Comment: @ Sythnet This is a good solution if the information doesn't need to dynamically change. If the information changes, you'll need to use javascript / jquery and update that hidden field before submit. So use this idea along with my answer.

Comment: Yeah, the information doesn't change and I got it working with the hidden text field, thanks for the information, if you could answer one more question though that be great! Why doesn't a label send information, is there a reason it was built to not send information?

Comment: Well, labels are meant to explain what the expected content of the related input field is, and since input fields have names that put it in context on the end the data is received, there generally wouldn't be a need for the label information to be included as well.

Comment: @spacebean I know this is an old thread. But just curious, if use `input` as hidden field, then people can actually manipulate that hidden field by going into Chrome tools such as inspect element, make it visible and change values accordingly right?

Answer (score 3):

Very easily done.

```
alert($('label').html());
```

Answer (score 2):

Without great changes in your code, you can get what you need using a hidden field initialized with the same value that the label.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the value of a label from a form post because the information is not sent. What you can do is add a hidden field to your form with the value of the label

Answer (score 0):

Labels are simply lables for any other visible entities on your HTML page, with the help of javascript and its libraries you may access the HTML within label to send it to the server.
But this approach is not good, as suggested by others, it would be better to use hidden fields to post such data without using javascript.

Further I would like to add that if your page is using HTML5 then you can use data attribute with most of the html tags to store data linked to those elements.
use jQuery to access those data, serialize it and send it to server through Ajax requests.